# Unable to drag events in FullCalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I have a FullCalendar app using React and the Resource-Timeline that is built by webpack. There are two odd issues I'm running into that may be related.

1. I am unable to drag events. This only happens on my current project, when I codePen the exact same code, everything works as expected.
2. The order of the plugins seems to impact the functionality. If I create the calendar with plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin]}, the interaction plugin doesn't work at all, but if I load it first everything except the dragging works. plugins={[interactionPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin]} This isn't a big deal, but might have something to do with what is happening with the dragging not working.

I don't know if the issue is with the build system or some other compatibility issue. I've spent days upon days trying to figure it out, but I'm not having any luck. I'm hoping someone can provide a suggestion for how I might troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Step 1..any errors in your console? P.S. If you want more help, please provide us with a [mre] of your issue, in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No errors in console. I would have loved to provide a reproducible example, only I can't. The problem only happens in my current project. I have created a new project and a codepen and can't reproduce it. I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot it and am probably just going to have to figure out a way to work around it. :-(

Comment: I should add that I blew out the entire node_modules directory and ran an npm install without any luck. I've updated all modules as well. I suspect the issue may have something to do with javascript or css in the current project so I'm going to try to eliminate that in my next test.

Comment: Maybe start a new project with just fullCalendar stuff, check it works, and then gradually add other stuff back in until there's an issue again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JoseLora, the code is functional, the problem was in the build system. I did not post code because it worked fine in a new project and Codepen. I realize how difficult it is to assist without code to look at.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone else if they run into this issue.

FullCalendar uses tslib as a dependency. If you install FullCalendar with "npm-force-resolutions" set in your package.json file AND you don't already have tslib, there is something about the way FullCalendar pulls down a copy of tslib that creates the issue. The following steps corrected the issue:

1. delete @fullcalendar from the node_modules folder
2. install tslib (npm install tslib)
3. install @fullcalendar

It's an oddball issue, so I may be the only one to ever run into it. I finally ended up using [webpack visualizer](http://%20https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/) to troubleshoot the issue. It does a great job of showing the dependency chain.